# Qt Layout Centers Itself

Tags: c++, qt, layout

I am newbie at Qt and I am developing a simple program to learn it. However I faced with a layout problem. When I change the layout of the window, the new layout centers itself in the window.

Let me explain the situation with images:

[image]

This is the main menu of the game. When the player clicks the `High Scores button`, the layout is changed. However, there is a position problem with `high score layout` like this:

[image]

I tried `QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QGridLayout` but, the result did not change. Also, here is the sample code:

```
QVBoxLayout* myLay = new QVBoxLayout();

gameBtn->hide();
passwordBtn->hide();
scoreBtn->hide();
quitBtn->hide();

QPushButton *backBtn = new QPushButton("Back to Menu" );
connect( backBtn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT( backToMenu()) );
backBtn->setGeometry(650,520,100,35); // Has no effect

QString header = "HIGH SCORES: ";
QLabel *headerLabel = new QLabel( header );
headerLabel->setGeometry(20,20,260,25); //Has no effect
headerLabel->setFont( QFont("Courier New", 28 ) );

myLay->addWidget(headerLabel);
myLay->addWidget(backBtn);

setLayout(myLay);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`QLayout::setAlignment(Qt::Alignment alignment)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qlayout.html#setAlignment-2) to set the alignment of your layout.

```
myLay->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop);
```